# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'env' of undefined

Tags: html, unit-testing, jasmine, environment-variables, typeerror

I used jasmine 1.2.0 and it worked perfectly. Now I am using the same code everything the same as it was, the only differance is that I moved to jasmine 2.0.1 and now its not working... all the tests fails, and the error I get is : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'env' of undefined ".

Here is the SpecRunner.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Jasmine Spec Runner</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../app/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../app/bower_components/font-awsome/css/font-awesome.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../app/bower_components/datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../app/css/style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../app/bower_components/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../app/bower_components/bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../app/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../app/bower_components/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../app/bower_components/backbone/backbone.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../app/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../app/bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../app/bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../app/bower_components/datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../app/bower_components/backbone-tastypie/backbone_tastypie/static/js/backbone-tastypie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../app/bower_components/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../app/bower_components/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../app/bower_components/backbone.localstorage/backbone.localStorage.js"></script>

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="jasmine-2.0.1/jasmine_favicon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jasmine-2.0.1/jasmine.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jasmine-2.0.1/jasmine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jasmine-2.0.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jasmine-2.0.1/boot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sinon.js"></script>


.
.
.


<!-- include spec files here... -->
.
.
.

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv();
        jasmineEnv.updateInterval = 1000;

        var htmlReporter = new jasmine.HtmlReporter();
        var oldResult = htmlReporter.reportRunnerResults;

        jasmineEnv.addReporter(htmlReporter);

        /* this is just for our automated tests */
        window.jasmine_phantom_reporter = new jasmine.ConsoleReporter;

        jasmineEnv.addReporter(jasmine_phantom_reporter);
        /*   */

        jasmineEnv.specFilter = function (spec) {
            return htmlReporter.specFilter(spec);
        };

        var currentWindowOnload = window.onload;
        window.onload = function() {
            if (currentWindowOnload) {
                currentWindowOnload();
            }
            execJasmine();


        };

        function execJasmine() {
            jasmineEnv.execute();
        }

    })();
</script>

</head>

<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should add the code of a basic test for which it fails and only the necessary dependencies for the test to fail and not all of them without version

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure that the `sinon.js` that you've included will support jasmine 2.0, as there were significant changes made to how jasmine works with the 2.0 release. Additionally, check out the [upgrade guide](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/upgrading.html) to help with converting your existing specs to work with 2.0.

On another note, as of 2.0, the `boot.js` file should do all of the work you have in your inline script block so that should no longer be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Version 2 of jasmine appears to use the `boot.js` file to load the settings and initiate jasmine. You also have this setup specified in your inline script. Try removing the inline script and allow jasmine to load via the included `boot.js` you already have in your script includes.